# Check if data attribute matches isChecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to verify if a check box is checked by default. So I added a data attribute called `data-state="true"`. Later on in the Javascript I am using the following code:

```
value = ($(this).attr('data-state') === $(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).attr('data-price') : 0;
```

but for some reason it always comes out to 0, I am not really sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Why not use the native `defaultChecked` property?

Comment: or `$(this).attr('checked') !== null` ?

Comment: because it is checked using javascript not with the html.

Answer (score 1):

```
true !== "true"
```

You are doing a string to boolean check.

Comment: I know that is what I am doing, is there a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the attribute `data-state`:

```
$(this).attr( 'data-state', $(this).prop( 'checked' ) );
```

I would suggest you use `data()`:

```
$(this).data( 'state', $(this).prop( 'checked' ) );
```

Which you can then read and compare as follows:

```
value = ($(this).data('state') == $(this).prop('checked')) ? $(this).data('price') : 0;
```